# Get SHA-1 for Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, sha1

I'm trying to get SHA-1 certificate for my Android Firebase project, following this instructions https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth. When I enter this command in my cmd:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

I supposed to be asked to enter password, where I should enter `android`. But I am getting this:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: it's the \ causing problems, remove that and type it on one line

Comment: Yes. That was the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the slash (`\`) in your command. Make sure it is all on one line and remove any slashes (`\`). Also keep in mind that the command prompt interprets commands on a single line, so do not spread the command across multiple lines as it will treat everything on a new line as a different command. Put everything on one line.

Answer (score 13):

There is another way to get SHA key for firebase project using android studio. follow this below instructions

**1. See Android Studio right panel, you'll find *GRADLE* tab there like this**
[image]

**2.Now Click on Gradle and you'll get this**

[image]

**3.You'll find your app name there.If not hit the *refresh* icon top-left corner.**

[image]

click on your *app name* and go like this 
***App Name > Tasks > android > signing report***

**Double click** on **signing report** and you'll find your ap **SHA-1** key in your RUN at bottom of the android studio like this

[image]

copy the **SHA1** key and use where you want.

Comment: This worked like a charm. The problem is that its not specific when they say to add the SHA-1 fingerprint for firebase of which file and from where exactly.